# Which language should I use to provide dynamic web content.

Tags: web-server

If I'm looking to serve dynamic content, which language is going to be the best option(fastest I guess). So I guess I'm really asking what is going to be the fastest compiler/interpreter. From what I've read Java seems to be bad idea, but I've nothing to compare the other options, Python, Ruby, PHP.

Comment: Hello Natt. Choice of programming languages is a very subjective topic and ergo I must close it as not constructive. If you choose a language though feel free to ask questions about it on [so]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Short: use ruby

Long: I have developed web-applications for 15 years and have not seen or heard anything that comes close to the ease of ruby on rails. But off course it always depends.

Sinatra (also a ruby framework) may be the better choice if it's just a small thing.

And even php may be good if it's a really small thing (1-2 pages). it certainly is easiest to deploy on a standard box. Php easily ends up a mess if it's bigger.

The speed you should probably be looking for is development speed, not execution.
Ruby on rails (possibly with puma web server) and database access will get you maybe 10 concurrent users on the pi. With sinatra (and a less complex application) maybe 20.

Also ruby comes with an excellent package management, bundler, easy but powerful templating language (erb) and lots of gems to get you up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about fastest, but php is the most common for dynamic content. What matters most is what language you are best at/have packages utilizing.

Comment: most common for dynamic content on Pi? I am really concerned with performance, so the fastest jitter/compiler/interpreter. The language isn't the issue really.

Comment: What, more exactly do you want it for? You could in fact use C++ instead if speed is of the greatest importance.

Comment: Good call, do you know any good c++ web frameworks suitable for the Pi. I'm just trying to avoid the sluggish performance i've read about regarding java